# Reading POP3 emails with PHP and IMAP issues

Tags: php, imap

**Problem**

---

I want to connect to my mail box on my domain name. Unfortunately I couldn't succeed so far.

```
/* mail information */
$hostname   = '{mail.domain.com:110/pop3}INBOX';
$user       = 'mail@domain.com';
$pass       = 'mypassword';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Mail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

**Error Output**

```
Cannot connect to Mail: Certificate failure for mail.domain.com: Self-signed certificate or untrusted authority: C=US, S=Someprovince, L=Sometown, O=none, OU=none, CN=localhost, E=webaster@localhost
```

I also tried following;

**1. approach**

```
$hostname = '{mail.domain.com:110}INBOX';
```

After quite long time of waiting;

```
Cannot connect to Mail: [CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response)
```

**2. approach**

```
$hostname   = '{mail.domain.com:110/pop3/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
```

Almost immediate response;

```
Cannot connect to Mail: Login aborted
```

At this point, I tried what I could find on PHP.net, Google and SOF without any success.

What could be the problem and what could be the solution? I don't think imap connection is hard to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've never used IMAP and POP in PHP, but it's evident to me that you're trying to connect via IMAP on a POP3 port. IMAP listens on port 143.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-open.php it can also connect pop3. I also tried imap with port 143. Same results.

Comment: Right. Have you tried the novalidate-cert method on port 143?

Comment: Yes. I tried all versions and possible ways are shown in manual without any success.

Comment: I noticed you are setting the password in variable $pass, but passing $password (empty) to imap_open().

Comment: Oh shoot, I didn't notice that. Now it is working. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `/novalidate-cert` in `hostname` parameter to bypass certificate validations in case you use self-signed certificates. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.imap-open.php for further information.

Comment: I forgot to mention that. Updated my question. Thank you for your time.